# Permalink Problems

Tags: permalinks

From the WordPress support forums:

> Hi, this is my website http://www.mp3ojax.com. I want to insert permalinks on the images on main page
>
> This is the code:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $metadataContent = ob_get_clean(); ?>
<?php if (trim($metadataContent) != ''): ?>
<div class="art-PostMetadataHeader">
<?php echo $metadataContent; ?>
</a>
```

> But I get urls like this:
>   http://mp3ojax.com/joseph-krikorian-artarutyun-2008/%3C/a%3E%3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%20class=
>
> please can someone help me?

**Edit:**

> Here is the full page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="art-contentLayout">
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar1.php'); ?><div class="art-content">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="art-Post">
    <div class="art-Post-tl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-tr"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-bl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-br"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-tc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-bc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cr"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-body">
<div class="art-Post-inner art-article">
<h2 class="art-PostHeaderIcon-wrapper">
<span class="art-PostHeader"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'kubrick'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a></span>
</h2>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php $icons = array(); ?>
<?php if (!is_page()): ?><?php ob_start(); ?><?php the_time(__('F jS, Y', 'kubrick')) ?>
<?php $icons[] = ob_get_clean(); ?><?php endif; ?><?php if (!is_page()): ?><?php ob_start(); ?><?php _e('Author', 'kubrick'); ?>: <a href="#" title="<?php _e('Author', 'kubrick'); ?>"><?php the_author() ?></a>
<?php $icons[] = ob_get_clean(); ?><?php endif; ?><?php if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)): ?><?php ob_start(); ?><?php edit_post_link(__('Edit', 'kubrick'), ''); ?>
<?php $icons[] = ob_get_clean(); ?><?php endif; ?><?php if (0 != count($icons)): ?>
<div class="art-PostHeaderIcons art-metadata-icons">
<?php echo implode(' | ', $icons); ?>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $metadataContent = ob_get_clean(); ?>
<?php if (trim($metadataContent) != ''): ?>
<div class="art-PostMetadataHeader">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo $metadataContent; ?></a>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<div class="art-PostContent">
<?php if (is_search()) the_excerpt(); else the_content(__('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;', 'kubrick')); ?>

</div>
<div class="cleared"></div>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php $icons = array(); ?>
<?php if (!is_page()): ?><?php ob_start(); ?><?php printf(__('Posted in %s', 'kubrick'), get_the_category_list(', ')); ?>
<?php $icons[] = ob_get_clean(); ?><?php endif; ?><?php if (!is_page() && get_the_tags()): ?><?php ob_start(); ?><?php the_tags(__('Tags:', 'kubrick') . ' ', ', ', ' '); ?>
<?php $icons[] = ob_get_clean(); ?><?php endif; ?><?php if (!is_page() && !is_single()): ?><?php ob_start(); ?><?php comments_popup_link(__('No Comments »', 'kubrick'), __('1 Comment »', 'kubrick'), __('% Comments »', 'kubrick'), '', __('Comments Closed', 'kubrick') ); ?>
<?php $icons[] = ob_get_clean(); ?><?php endif; ?><?php if (0 != count($icons)): ?>
<div class="art-PostFooterIcons art-metadata-icons">
<?php echo implode(' | ', $icons); ?>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $metadataContent = ob_get_clean(); ?>
<?php if (trim($metadataContent) != ''): ?>
<div class="art-PostMetadataFooter">
<?php echo $metadataContent; ?>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>

    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
$prev_link = get_previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &raquo;', 'kubrick'));
$next_link = get_next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries', 'kubrick'));
?>
<?php if ($prev_link || $next_link): ?>
<div class="art-Post">
    <div class="art-Post-tl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-tr"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-bl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-br"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-tc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-bc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cr"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-body">
<div class="art-Post-inner art-article">

<div class="art-PostContent">

<div class="navigation">
 <?php if(function_exists('wp_page_numbers')) : wp_page_numbers(); endif; ?>

</div>

</div>
<div class="cleared"></div>

</div>

    </div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<h2 class="center"><?php _e('Not Found', 'kubrick'); ?></h2>
<p class="center"><?php _e('Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn’t here.', 'kubrick'); ?></p>
<?php if(function_exists('get_search_form')) get_search_form(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar2.php'); ?>
</div>
<div class="cleared"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Is this solved? Was it the missing "? If so, can you accept Thomas' answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really enough code as an example to fully understand if there is any additional issues, but the main thing which is causing the URL's to not work is the fact that the opening anchor tag is not closed. Adding a `">` to the end of the first line should fix the issue. In addition the `art-PostMetadataHeader` div should be closed.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $metadataContent = ob_get_clean(); ?>
<?php if (trim($metadataContent) != ''): ?>
<div class="art-PostMetadataHeader">
    <?php echo $metadataContent; ?>
</div>
</a>
```

Having said that, nesting a block level element such as a `div` inside of an inline element such as an anchor is not standards compliant, but this code would have the same effect of linking all the `$metadataContent`, while being standards compliant.

```
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $metadataContent = ob_get_clean(); ?>
<?php if (trim($metadataContent) != ''): ?>
<div class="art-PostMetadataHeader">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $metadataContent; ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget the `;` after `the_permalink()` or it might break things even further.

Comment: This is the best answer even if it isn't what fixed the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I found it:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="art-PostContent">
<?php if (is_search()) the_excerpt(); else the_content(__('Read the rest of this entry »', 'kubrick')); ?>

</div></a>
```